# Howto read extensions from X.509 in Java?

Tags: java, x509certificate, x509, verify

I have created a `X.509` certificate with `openssl`, the certificate has a custom extension which I need to be able to read in Java code. I created the certificate with the following code:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key myCA.key -out mtCA.csr -days 1000 -config openssl.cfg
```

Now what is the simplest way to read the value of the extension in the certificate in Java code? Or more general whats the simplest way to parse a `x509` certificate?

Answer (score -1):

Use java.security.cert.CertificateFactory and [java.security.cert.X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)

```
private void read(File file) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);
    // read X509Certificate
}
```